# Prisma one to many query, use that data to find others with same one to many relation issue

Tags: arrays, object, prisma

New to using the Prisma model, and I was able to get all my tables working to return multiple one : one and one: many relationships.  I have an array returned for a single item with all the supporting data

```
id : 1
name : Widget1
colors
  0 : red
  1 : blue
  3 : green
```

So the item i returned is wideget1, it contains 3 colors ina 1:many relationship.  I returned this using include colors : true

This query is completed and returned the array at data, so i can use data.id ext, but I want to return 5 randome other items that share a color erelationship as well but prisma will not allow

```
const dataSeconds = await prisma.widgets.findMany({
    where: { colors: data.colors.id },
```

the error is that "colors" is not a property data, although I see it when id do a

```
<pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
```

Thanks, Each time I feel I have this i run into a I have no idea moment.

when I return the data I can access the data until it is in an array (colors)

```
id : 1,
name : Widget1,
colors : [
  { id: 0, color: red},
  { id: 1, color: blue},
  { id: 2, color: green}
]
```

In react I can  not access the array (colors) directly and I cant seem to get map to do what I think it should

Answer (score 0):

Found I need to map out the array parts returned by prisma when joining one tom many.

```
{props.colors.map(function (d, id) { .. Use data here .. }
```